# Different Idem font shapes in biblatex-dw

Tags: biblatex, capitalization, small-caps, biblatex-dw

I have a problem with the font shape of the `idem` words in `biblatex-dw`.

In the MWE one sees that the word `Ders` in the first footnote is typeset in smallcaps with the original processed word being `ders` in lowercase.

In the second footnote `Ders` is also typeset in smallcaps, but with the original processed word being `Ders` so with a capital first letter. This has the effect that it looks different than the initial one.

The `URL` text is fine to be typeset as smallcaps with the original processed word being `url`.

I would like both `Ders` to be typeset the same. For this I tried to redefine the `\mkbibmacro` making the uppercase acronym first lowercase, then capitalize the first letter and finally setting it in smallcaps. However, the `\MakeCapital` doesn't seem to work. And even if it would work I think the `URL` would be effected to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw,xref=true,mincrossrefs=1,edsuper=true,autocite=footnote,ibidtracker=constrict,idemtracker=constrict,ibidpage=true,namefont=smallcaps,citedas=true,annotation=true,idemfont=smallcaps]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{\textsc{\MakeCapital{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}
@Collection{ABC,
    editor = {Cornelisse, J. W.},
    title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
    year = {1979},
        gender  = {sm},
    publisher = {Pitman},
        url = {https://google.com}
}

@InCollection{ABC2,
        crossref    = {ABC},
    author = {Cornelisse, J. W.},
    title = {Rocket Propulsion II},
    year = {1979},
        gender  = {sm},
    publisher = {Pitman},
        url = {https://google.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{MWE.bib}



\begin{document}
    Second book\autocite[][]{ABC2}. \textsc{ders} should look like \textsc{Ders} but \textsc{url} is fine

        First book\autocite[][]{ABC} where \textsc{Ders} is typeset correctly.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-dw` actively disables the automatic capitalisation tracker for "idem" in editor and translator position with `\midsentence*`. The following MWE re-enables it. The definitions of `useeditor` and `usetranslator` are copies from `standard-dw.bbx` with just the `\midsentence*` removed.

Since "idem"/"ders." is not an acronym `\mkbibacro` has no word in the formatting. The code below shows that the formatting is controlled by `\mkidem`, but there is no need to redefine that macro here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw, xref=true, mincrossrefs=1, edsuper=true, autocite=footnote, ibidtracker=constrict, idemtracker=constrict, ibidpage=true, namefont=smallcaps, citedas=true, annotation=true, idemfont=smallcaps]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{useeditor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
    {\ifbool{bbx:edbyidem}
      {\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
       \addspace}%
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
   \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
   \clearname{editor}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}

\renewbibmacro*{usetranslator}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{translator}
    {\ifbool{bbx:edbyidem}
      {\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
       \addspace}%
      {\printnames[byeditor]{translator}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printnames[byeditor]{translator}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
   \usebibmacro{translatorstrg}%
   \clearname{translator}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Collection{ABC,
  editor    = {Cornelisse, J. W.},
  title     = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
  year      = {1979},
  gender    = {sm},
  publisher = {Pitman},
  url       = {https://google.com}
}
@InCollection{ABC2,
  crossref  = {ABC},
  author    = {Cornelisse, J. W.},
  title     = {Rocket Propulsion II},
  year      = {1979},
  gender    = {sm},
  publisher = {Pitman},
  url       = {https://google.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Second book\autocite[][]{ABC2}. \textsc{ders} should look like \textsc{Ders} but \textsc{url} is fine

  First book\autocite[][]{ABC} where \textsc{Ders} is typeset correctly.
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote 1 "J. W. Cornelisse: Rocket Propulsion II, in: Ders. (Hrsg.): Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics, 1979, url: https://google.com."]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wasn't aware of this change as it seems to be undocumented in the official manual.